# Mod rewrite problem wildcarding inside first slashes in uri

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite like this:

```
  /v2/auth /v2/myphp.php
  /v1/auth /v1/myphp.php
```

Should be quite simple but I am running into problems.
Here is an example that should ultimately do what I want, the   rewritecondition works but the rewrite fails:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v\d+/auth$ [NC]
RewriteRule "^.*(v\d+).*$" "/$1/myphp.php" [L]
```

The rewriterule below  works with http://mydomaindotcom/v2/auth :

```
  RewriteRule "^.*auth$" "/v2/myphp.php" [L]
```

But this works also with same url:

```
  RewriteRule "^.*a.*$" "/v2/myphp.php" [L]
```

But this fails, and I guess that indicates its a problem catching whats inside the first slashes?:

```
  RewriteRule "^.*v.*$" "/v2/myphp.php" [L]
```

would appreciate any help to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteCond is to check that it is "/vDIGITS/auth", where DIGITS is [0-9].  So your line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v\d+/auth$ [NC]
```

is ok.  `\d+` matches at least one digit.  No problem there.

Then your RewriteRule is to take the DIGITS and use it to build your target.
So use the same regex from your RewriteCond and add parenthesis like so:

```
RewriteRule "^/(v\d+)/auth$" "/$1/myphp.php" [L]
```

Since you know the RewriteCond matched that regex, using it in the RewriteRule is a win-win.

FYI is you want the browsers to leave you alone for future requests, make the rewrite permanent with flag "R=301" after the "L" flag.

Comment: The problem is that nothing within the first the sashes (in this example /v1/) can be matched. As soon as its there it wont match.
I have tried exactely  with your example and it also fails.  Note that "RewriteRule "^.*v.*auth$" "/v1/IBAuth.php" [L]
" fails but "RewriteRule "^.*auth$" "/v1/IBAuth.php" [L]
" works.  As soon as I try to match something within the first slashes "/v1/" it fails!